# Can I distribute jquery.pack.js file along with my plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, licensing

I created a jquery plugin for tutorial purposes.Now I want to bundle jquery source file along with my plugin and demo html file.Can i do it.What are the license restrictions in this case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is dual licensed under the [MIT](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE.txt) and [GPL](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/GPL-LICENSE.txt) license.
From the [jQuery project](http://jquery.org/license/) website:

> The MIT License is recommended for most projects. It is simple and
>   easy to understand and it places almost no restrictions on what you
>   can do with a jQuery project.
>
> If the GPL suits your project better you are also free to use a jQuery
>   project under that license.
>
> You don’t have to do anything special to choose one license or the
>   other and you don’t have to notify anyone which license you are using.
>   You are free to use a jQuery project in commercial projects as long as
>   the copyright header is left intact.

So just go ahead and bundle it all up. Usually the packed version also comes with the official copyright header.

Comment: Isn't it called `jquery-{version}.min.js`?

Comment: Ignore... Found. It's jquery compressed with Dean Edwards' Packer

Comment: Good point. I would just recommend to make sure that the original copyright header is in the file being used.